# How can I revert a property to its default value?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Property Name() As String = "default_name"

Sub InitializeFields()
    Name = String.Empty
    '
    '
    '
    Name = Name.GetDefaultValue.ToString    '   an example

End Sub
```

Programmatically, how can I revert the default value "default_name" of any property?

Comment: The initial value is not the default value. If you want to be able to reset to an actual default value then you need to add a DefaultValue attribute to the property itself. That attribute is what is used when you right-click a property in the designer and select Rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you ought to do this with an actual default value:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Thing

    <DefaultValue("Hello World")>
    Public Property WithDefault As String

    Public Property WithoutDefault As String

End Class
```

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim something As New Thing

        something.WithDefault = "First"
        something.WithoutDefault = "Second"

        If TrySetDefaultValue(something, NameOf(something.WithDefault)) Then
            Console.WriteLine($"{NameOf(something.WithDefault)} reset to ""{something.WithDefault}""")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine($"No default value for {NameOf(something.WithDefault)}")
        End If

        If TrySetDefaultValue(something, NameOf(something.WithoutDefault)) Then
            Console.WriteLine($"{NameOf(something.WithoutDefault)} reset to ""{something.WithoutDefault}""")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine($"No default value for {NameOf(something.WithoutDefault)}")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function TryGetDefaultValue([object] As Object, propertyName As String, ByRef value As Object) As Boolean
        Dim attribute = [object].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttribute(Of DefaultValueAttribute)()

        If attribute Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        value = attribute.Value

        Return True
    End Function

    Public Function TrySetDefaultValue([object] As Object, propertyName As String) As Boolean
        Dim [property] = [object].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
        Dim attribute = [property].GetCustomAttribute(Of DefaultValueAttribute)()

        If attribute Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim value = attribute.Value

        [property].SetValue([object], value)

        Return True
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: great hint, I, fortunately, figure out what I was missing. come back with complete coding soon.

Comment: thanks for introducing the custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There's no out-of-the-box way to somehow revert a property to its (custom) initial value. Once it's changed, it's over; the original value is lost.

Assuming the property belongs to a class (and that it doesn't get modified in the constructor), you *could* retrieve the value by creating a temporary instance of the class. For example:

```
Class SomeClass
    Public Property Name As String = "default_name"

    Sub InitializeFields()
        Name = String.Empty
        '
        '
        '
        Name = New SomeClass().Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

**However,** that's not very robust and could get ugly really fast. The way I would do this is by storing the default value in a constant:

```
Private Const DefaultName As String = "default_name"

Public Property Name As String = DefaultName

Sub InitializeFields()
    Name = String.Empty
    '
    '
    '
    Name = DefaultName
End Sub
```

And then you can do that for each property that you need to later access its original value.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class clsThisClass
    '   each property have attribute of default value
    <DefaultValue(0)>
    Public Property RecordCount() As Long = 0

    <DefaultValue("a")>
    Public Property SQL() As String = String.Empty

    <DefaultValue(0)>
    Public Property IndexID() As Long = 0

    <DefaultValue("b")>
    Public Property Name() As String = String.Empty

    <DefaultValue("c")>
    Public Property Title() As String = String.Empty

    <DefaultValue("d")>
    Public Property Document_No() As String = String.Empty

    <DefaultValue("abc")>
    Public Property Company_Code() As String = String.Empty

    Sub InitializeFields()
        With Me

            RecordCount = 28
            IndexID = 10
            Name = "name"
            Title = "title"
            Document_No = "doc_no"
            Company_Code = "com_code"

            Debug.WriteLine(RecordCount)
            Debug.WriteLine(IndexID)
            Debug.WriteLine(Name)
            Debug.WriteLine(Document_No)
            Debug.WriteLine(Company_Code)

'    revert or reset all properties to default value upon initialization
            Dim aType As Type = GetType(clsThisClass)
            '    each property of class
            For Each pi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In aType.GetProperties()
                '    grab assigned default value of the property
                Dim attribute = Me.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name.ToString).GetCustomAttribute(Of DefaultValueAttribute)()
                Try
                    Dim value As Object = Nothing
                    '    convert value type according to the type of the property
                    value = CTypeDynamic(value, GetType(Attribute))

                    If Not attribute Is Nothing Then
                        value = attribute.Value
                        '    set default value
                        pi.SetValue(Me, value)

                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Next

            Debug.WriteLine(RecordCount)
            Debug.WriteLine(IndexID)
            Debug.WriteLine(Name)
            Debug.WriteLine(Document_No)
            Debug.WriteLine(Company_Code)

        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

28

10

name

doc_no

com_code

0

0

a

b

c

d

abc

initialized all properties with a default value at once.
in my scenario, I have numerous classes and have several properties.
by doing these few lines of code. I can copy-paste in each class at initializing method. it saved lots of time for writing code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).